# Angular router Connection forwarding issue

Tags: angular, angular-router, routerlink

I'm having a problem with Angular routerLink, can you please help me?

I Deleted AppComponent and created LoginComponent instead of this component.
The home page is now the Login Login page.
No problem so far.

I wrote routerLink"/erp" to the Login button on the login page.
Component page to call: ErpComponent I could not fetch this page.

other redirects are working, just not going to Erp Component page.

Can you help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t95qN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17flS.png)

Answer (score 0):

First guess: the matcher is wrong and redirects all requests to "" (login).
Please try this:

```
const routes: Routes [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent ),
  { path: 'erp', component: ErpComponent ),
  { path: 'basvuru-yap', component: BasvuruYapComponent }
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' ),
];
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, is there any other way?

Comment: more information needed - can you share the code on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com)?